# mongodb sort function is not working when trying to sort alphabetically

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I know this is a very basic thing, but I didn't get a solution so far. the code prop is a string, when I try to sort with it, I'm getting the response unsorted. consider that the DB is having all documents with codes from r1 to r12.

I don't have enough reputation to post images so please find them here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPU8a.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT2if.png

Comment: The problem is that you are sorting a text field, but expecting it sort numerically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query for the sorting. Replace **collectionName** with your collection.

```
db.getCollection("**collectionName**").find({}).sort({codes:1}).collation({locale:"en_US",numericOrdering:true});
```

Try this out and do let me know :)

Comment: Welcome @DilshanMadushanka!  glad the answer helped you. Do upvote when you get the rights to upvote